# pandas: What is the best way to do fillna() on a (multiindexed) DataFrame with the most frequent value from every group?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fill, missing-data

There is a DataFrame with some NaN values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], 'B': [1, 1, np.NaN, 2, 3, np.NaN, 3, 4]})

   A    B
0  1  1.0
1  1  1.0
2  1  NaN <-
3  1  2.0
4  2  3.0
5  2  NaN <-
6  2  3.0
7  2  4.0
```

Set label 'A' as an index:

```
df.set_index(['A'], inplace=True)
```

Now there are two groups with the indices 1 and 2:

```
     B
A     
1  1.0
1  1.0
1  NaN <-
1  2.0
2  3.0
2  NaN <-
2  3.0
2  4.0
```

**What is the best way to do fillna() on the DataFrame with the *most frequent* value from each group?**

So, I would like to do a call of something like this:

```
df.B.fillna(df.groupby('A').B...)
```

and get:

```
     B
A     
1  1.0
1  1.0
1  1.0 <-
1  2.0
2  3.0
2  3.0 <-
2  3.0
2  4.0
```

I hope there's a way and it also works with multiindex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- groupby column `A` and apply `fillna()` to B within each group;
- drop missing values from the series, and do `value_counts`, use `idxmax()` to pick up the most frequent value;

Assuming there are no groups where all values are missing:

```
df['B'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.dropna().value_counts().idxmax()))
df
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It works. But it seems there's no need to drop missing values explicitly because they are automatically excluded by the groupby() call.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure if that is true. It's possible value counts exclude the missing values. I can't test now, will check later.

Comment: I forgot to add link: [NA values in GroupBy](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#na-values-in-groupby).

Comment: The link says group by excludes missing values in group variable A in your case not necessarily other columns (B in your case) in the data frame.

Comment: I've tested it, and you are right - it excludes only group variables. Thanks again!